# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' even after using np.multiply

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, casting

I have the following which works along the rows of a dataframe. I have
tried many things, like `np.multiply` or `np.array` to make that
multiplication works but so far to no avail. I have also converted
factor to an `int` by multiplying and then dividing it by 10, but
nothing either. I have wrapped all my operands individually into
`np.array()`, and also have tried to `np.multiply` around every single
operation, but I still get that error.

```
factor = somefloatnumber  # i.e 0.4
def func(row): 
   return row *factor / np.sum(row)   
df2 =  df1.apply(func, axis=1)
```

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Here is a sample of the data I am using.

```
                    A       B          C         D         E
2006-04-28 A       69.62     69.62    3.518     65.09     69.62
           B       27.78    7.7       27.78      27.7       27
           C        0.23     0.22     0.02      0.23      0.21

2006-05-01 A       71.5      71.5      6.522     65.16      71.5
           B      28.4828   28.4828    28.4828   28.4828   28.4828
           C      0.249841  0.249841  0.0227897  0.227687  0.249841
```

Comment: Give us a sample representative input dataframe?

Comment: ok done. it's financial data downloaded

Comment: Added pandas tag, so that experts on it could help.

Comment: This error usually arises when trying to multiply a string by a non-integer number, can you check whether all the values in the dataframe are numbers?

Comment: @AlvaroP thanks yea it'a all numbers

Comment: perhaps how could i convert the entire dataframe besides the index to floats?

Comment: What does `df1.dtypes` give you?

Comment: i get this `Series([], dtype: object)`

Comment: Could you fix the code?  You define `func`, but then you use `df1.apply(weight, axis=1)`.  `weight` is not defined.

Comment: ok thnks. done. weight was func.

Comment: @Thanos think i found the answer. plz check.

Comment: @AlvaroP - think i found the answer. plz check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 
`convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` has done the trick!
 It attempts to infer better dtype for object columns
 see:                                                      http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html

In the case of my issue above, you would use it this way

```
df1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).apply(func,axis=1).
```

However, i get a Future warning:

> FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type
>   specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.

But it works.

Comment: So it seems that your entries were not numbers, but something else, or maybe mixed types. Good it works anyway!